# Cannot initiate a simple Supersized in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, supersized

I am trying to use the Jquery plugin Supersized and i cant. I am working with Magento. i have sustitute all the $  by jQuery inside the supersized library. And i have added this: jQuery.noConflict(); just before the start of the function. Here is my code, i copy the script and the html. I dont know why it doesnt work, can anyone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery.fn.supersized.options = {
      startwidth: 1440,
      startheight: 900,
      vertical_center: 1,
      slideshow: 1,
      navigation: 1,
      thumbnail_navigation: 0,
      transition: 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
      pause_hover: 1,
      slide_counter: 1,
      slide_captions: 1,
      slide_interval: 3000,
      slides : [
         {image : "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/portada_slider/slider1.jpg') ?>"} ,
         {image : "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/portada_slider/slider2.jpg') ?>"} 

      ]
   };

 });

</script>

<div id="supersized"></div>
```

Comment: i am a begginer with magento! i am getting crazy!

Answer (score 1):

### Note

I don't see any function named `supersized()` so how it will work? your process is wrong. Read about jQuery plugin making process.

---

You used

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {..
```

and

```
jQuery(function(){..
```

both use any one because the are same and be sure that:

- you added jQuery library first

**Full code**

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery.fn.supersized.options = {
      startwidth: 1440,
      startheight: 900,
      vertical_center: 1,
      slideshow: 1,
      navigation: 1,
      thumbnail_navigation: 0,
      transition: 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
      pause_hover: 1,
      slide_counter: 1,
      slide_captions: 1,
      slide_interval: 3000,
      slides : [
         {image : 'photo1.jpg'} ,
         {image : 'photo2.jpg'} 

      ]
   };
  jQuery('#supersized').supersized(); 
 });
```

Comment: first of all thanks! then tell you that i have delete "jQuery('document').ready(function() {.." and i am sure that i have added Jquery library, i can see it with firebug :(

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.fn.supersized.options = {
        startwidth: 1440,
        startheight: 900,
        vertical_center: 1,
        slideshow: 1,
        navigation: 1,
        thumbnail_navigation: 0,
        transition: 1,
        //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
        pause_hover: 1,
        slide_counter: 1,
        slide_captions: 1,
        slide_interval: 3000,
        slides: [
            {image: 'photo1.jpg'},
            {image: 'photo2.jpg'}
        ]
    };
    jQuery('#supersized').supersized();
});​
```

No need to include both :

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
jQuery(function(){
```

they are the same thing

Comment: first of all thanks! then tell you that i have delete "jQuery('document').ready(function() {.." but it doesnt works :(